# Remove and Replace Printed items

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, python-3.2

I was wondering if it was possible to remove items you have printed in Python - not from the Python GUI, but from the command prompt.
e.g.

```
a = 0  
for x in range (0,3):  
    a = a + 1  
    b = ("Loading" + "." * a)
print (a)
```

so it prints

```
>>>Loading   
>>>Loading. 
>>>Loading.. 
>>>Loading...
```

But, my problem is I want this all on one line, and for it it remove it self when something else comes along. So instead of printing `"Loading", "Loading.", "Loading...` I want it to print `"Loading."`, then it removes what is on the line and replaces it with `"Loading.."` and then removes `"Loading.."` and replaces it (on the same line) with `"Loading..."`. It's kind of hard to describe.

p.s I have tried to use the Backspace character but it doesn't seem to work (`"\b"`)

Comment: Whats the point of the `a` variable here? You can just use x as your variable and it will do the same thing!

Comment: Two questions: 1. shouldn't be the `print()` command indentet to the level of the inner of the for-loop? Currently, your code doesn't print some kind of progress, but only the final state. 2. shouldn't it be `print (b)`? Currently only integers are printed, not the `"Loading"` as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Just use CR to go to beginning of the line.

```
import time
for x in range (0,5):  
    b = "Loading" + "." * x
    print (b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It works in windows 7 basic terminal. In python 2.7, I simply use `print "whatever to be removed\r",` Thanks!

Comment: Any idea for terminal _( IDLE )_?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write("\033[K")` to clear the previous print

Comment: @h0ussni I don't know sorcery that is but it works great

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')` erase and go to beginning of line

Comment: Side note: to make this work in jupyter (in python3), use: `print("\r", b, end="")`

Comment: To clear all or n previously printed lines and move the cursor back to the start without flushing the entire console output every time (`os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')` cross OS compatible) use `cursor_up = '\x1b[1A';erase_line = '\x1b[2K';print("hi\nyou\nthere\nletstry!");print((cursor_up + erase_line)*4 +cursor_up);print("hi\nyou\nthere\nletstry!")`

Comment: Instead of `"." * x`, you should try `"." * (x % 3 + 1)` to avoid stuff like `Loading......`

Comment: in VS Code, and in Notebooks (ipynb), use these together:
    `print("\r" , end="")`
    `print("delta = ", delta, end="")`

Comment: @DSH's answer also works in PyCharm, thanks

Answer (score 145):

One way is to use [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
import sys
import time
for i in range(10):
    print("Loading" + "." * i)
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F") # Cursor up one line
    time.sleep(1)
```

Also sometimes useful (for example if you print something shorter than before):

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[K") # Clear to the end of line
```

Comment: Doesn't  work in python notebooks :(

Comment: Is it necessary to use sys.stdout.write() ?
Can you just do
print("\033[K",end='') ?

Comment: @Trevor This answer was written to work in both Python 2 and 3.  I know the question is tagged "python-3.x", but back in 2011 hardly anyone was using Python 3, so I wrote an answer that works in both versions.  If you are using Python 3, you can use `print(..., end="")` if you prefer.

Comment: Could you theoretically do `sys.stdout.write("\033[F" * 2)` if you wanted to cursor up 2 lines?

Comment: @madladzen This should work. The ANSI sequence also supports a parameter, so you could also use `sys.stdout.write("\033[2F")`.

Comment: I know I'm late, but my two cents: `"\033[F" * 2`, or `"\033[2F"` don't always work, as python adds the new line AFTER you go higher. So if you try to go 2 lines above and you only have one line printed, you will print the new thing on the next line, but if you have more than 1 line, the last one will be rewritten

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I can't quite follow. `sys.stdout.write()` does not add any newline characters. `print()` does, which is why the code isn't using it. This answer was originally written with Python 2 in mind. In Python  3, you can also use `print(..., end="")`, as already mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: My mistake. I was replying to a comment, and misread the `write` instead of `print`. What I was talking about was a `print("\033[F" * 2)` with no `end=''`

Answer (score 42):

```
import sys
import time

a = 0  
for x in range (0,3):  
    a = a + 1  
    b = ("Loading" + "." * a)
    # \r prints a carriage return first, so `b` is printed on top of the previous line.
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+b)
    time.sleep(0.5)
print (a)
```

Note that you might have to run `sys.stdout.flush()` right after `sys.stdout.write('\r'+b)` depending on which console you are doing the printing to have the results printed when requested without any buffering.

Comment: This works without Constant jitters in pycharm's console. The print with end ="" flickers alot in pycharm's Console

Comment: Works great on Spyder 5