# How to overwrite the previous print to stdout?

Tags: python

If I had the following code:

```
for x in range(10):
     print(x)
```

I would get the output of

```
1
2
etc..
```

What I would like to do is instead of printing a newline, I want to replace the previous value and overwrite it with the new value on the same line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Remove and Replace Printed items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/python-remove-and-replace-printed-items)

Comment: As a side note, ensure you get the answer which able to flush entire line if previous line **longer** than current line.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

## Simple Version

One way is to use the carriage return (`'\r'`) character to return to the start of the line without advancing to the next line.

#### Python 3

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x, end='\r')
print()
```

#### Python 2.7 forward compatible

```
from __future__ import print_function
for x in range(10):
    print(x, end='\r')
print()
```

#### Python 2.7

```
for x in range(10):
    print '{}\r'.format(x),
print
```

#### Python 2.0-2.6

```
for x in range(10):
    print '{0}\r'.format(x),
print
```

In the latter two (Python 2-only) cases, the comma at the end of the print statement tells it not to go to the next line. The last print statement advances to the next line so your prompt won't overwrite your final output.

## Line Cleaning

If you can’t guarantee that the new line of text is not shorter than the existing line, then you just need to add a “clear to end of line” escape sequence, `'\x1b[1K'` (`'\x1b'` = ESC):

```
for x in range(75):
    print('*' * (75 - x), x, end='\x1b[1K\r')
print()
```

## Long Line Wrap

All these methods assume you’re not writing more than the length of the line. The carriage return only returns to the start of the current line, so if your output is longer than a line, you’ll only erase the last line.

If this is enough of a problem that you need to control it, you can disable line wrapping to keep the cursor from wrapping to the next line. (Instead, the cursor sticks to the end of the line, and successive characters overwrite.)

Line wrap is disabled with `print('\x1b[7l', end='')` and re-enabled with `print('\x1b[7h', end='')`. **Note that there is no automatic re-enable of line wrap at any point:** don’t leave the terminal broken if an exception ends your program!

Comment: This works, but I don't understand a couple of the parts...  '{0}' and .format

Comment: That is introduced in Python 2.6 and (I'm told) is the standard way of formatting strings in Python 3; the `%` operator is deprecated.  Basically, all strings now have a [format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method. In this case, the `{0}` means "the first argument to `format()`" (counting starts at 0).

Comment: Not an option if you have to use some Windows-only software and don't have the chops to run a VM.

Comment: From another thread, `sys.stdout.write("\033[K")` can clear the line before you start printing. Useful if you print something shorter than before.

Comment: And if you want to be cross-terminal, `re.sub(r'\$<\d+>[/*]?', '', curses.tigetstr('el') or '')` will give you the correct erase-to-end-of-line string for whatever terminal the user has. Remember to initialize `curses` with something like `curses.setupterm(fd=sys.stdout.fileno())`, and use `sys.stdout.isatty()` to make sure your output isn't being redirected to a file. See http://code.activestate.com/recipes/475116/ for a full Python module with cursor control and color support.

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work if you use `time.sleep()` after the `print "something\r",` statement. The caret returns to the beginning of the line, but it won't overwrite.
Try the following: `print "Thing to erase\r", ; time.sleep(1) ; print "--------------\r",` and you will notice it doesn't replace with dashes. (current environment is Windows 7)

Comment: @PhilMacKay: I tried that in python on my Mac:
In [3]: print "Thing to erase\r", ; time.sleep(1) ; print "--------------\r",
--------------
I think your problem is Windows and its different line ends. Try this: `import curses; curses.setupterm(fd=sys.stdout.fileno()); print(hex(curses.tigetstr('cr')));` It should print the hex codes of the character sequence to go to the start of the line.

Comment: I don't see the need for format in python 3. wouldn't `end='\r'` work just as well?

Comment: If the new line is shorter than the previous line, the tail of the previous line will remain

Comment: @ElliottB Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that code, I was just using a bunch of spaces before

Comment: @ElliottB It works on any terminal that handles VTxxx or ANSI control codes. If you get a totally dumb terminal... you have to use the spaces.

Comment: I would like to note that if you try to print a message that fills the entire console width, the carriage return won't work. Your message has to be less than the console width (which I discovered after a couple hours of debugging). I believe this is due to the fact that the carriage return has to be on the same line as the message to clear the message out.

Comment: @crxyz That’s correct, and there is a way to handle that, but it has caveats. I’ll edit it in.

Answer (score 112):

Since I ended up here via Google but am using Python 3, here's how this would work in Python 3:

```
for x in range(10):
    print("Progress {:2.1%}".format(x / 10), end="\r")
```

Related answer here: [How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102749/in-python-3-how-can-i-suppress-the-newline-after-a-print-statement-with-the-comm)

Comment: I tried this and it mostly works fine. The only problem is it's not erasing prior output on that line, for instance: if your first loop print `testing` and your second loop print `test` the output after the second pass will still be `testing` - now I see that @Nagasaki45 pointed this out

Comment: in an ipython notebook, i have to do: `print("\r", message, end="")`

Comment: This works great, it does not erase the line but using enough whitespaces in the following print does the job (although it's not elegant).
One comment I might add is that this does not work in VS Code's debug console, but it works in the terminal.

Comment: @EricUldall  and @PhilMacKay ,the trick is to print some space after your message . For example: 
`print("Progress {:2.1%}    ".format(x), end="\r")`

So when the length of x change from 3 digits to 2 digits, the trailing space will erase the extra number.

Answer (score 35):

[@Mike DeSimone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419488/4298200) will probably work most of the time. But...

```
for x in ['abc', 1]:
    print '{}\r'.format(x),

-> 1bc
```

This is because the `'\r'` only goes back to the beginning of the line but doesn't clear the output.

If POSIX support is enough for you, the following would clear the current line and leave the cursor at its beginning:

```
print '\x1b[2K\r',
```

It uses ANSI escape code to clear the terminal line. More info can be found [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and in [this great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAitSilLDUA).

### Other approach

This other, (arguably worse) solution I have found looks like this:

```
last_x = ''
for x in ['abc', 1]:
    print ' ' * len(str(last_x)) + '\r',
    print '{}\r'.format(x),
    last_x = x

-> 1
```

One advantage is that it will work on windows too.

Comment: I made a function out of the 'old answer' that works properly (even on Windows), see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43952192/965332

Answer (score 29):

I had the same question before visiting this thread. For me the sys.stdout.write worked only if I properly flush the buffer i.e.

```
for x in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+str(x))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Without flushing, the result is printed only at the end out the script

Comment: Also good idea to fill rest of the string with spaces like `stringvar.ljust(10,' ')` in case of strings with variable length.

Comment: @chris, Don et al. this is Python 2, most of the other answers are Python 3. Everyone should be using Python 3 now; Python 2 is end-of-life in 2020.

Answer (score 18):

Suppress the newline and print `\r`.

```
print 1,
print '\r2'
```

or write to stdout:

```
sys.stdout.write('1')
sys.stdout.write('\r2')
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a cleaner, more "plug-and-play", version of @Nagasaki45's answer. Unlike many other answers here, it works properly with strings of different lengths. It achieves this by clearing the line with just as many spaces as the length of the last line printed print. Will also work on Windows.

```python
def print_statusline(msg: str):
    last_msg_length = len(getattr(print_statusline, 'last_msg', ''))
    print(' ' * last_msg_length, end='\r')
    print(msg, end='\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()  # Some say they needed this, I didn't.
    setattr(print_statusline, 'last_msg', msg)
```

### Usage

Simply use it like this:

```python
for msg in ["Initializing...", "Initialization successful!"]:
    print_statusline(msg)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This small test shows that lines get cleared properly, even for different lengths:

```python
for i in range(9, 0, -1):
    print_statusline("{}".format(i) * i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: This is a great solution as it elegantly cleans the previous output to its full length without just printing an arbitrary number of white spaces (which is what I had previously resorted to!) Thanks

Comment: I have never seen an attribute attached to a function before. nice trick.

Answer (score 11):

```
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5) # shows how its working
    print("\r {}".format(x), end="")
```

time.sleep(0.5) is to show how previous output is erased and new output is printed 
"\r" when its at the start of print message , it gonna erase previous output before  new output.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
import time
while True:
    print("Hi ", end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Bob", end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

It worked for me. The  `end="\r"` part is making it overwrite the previous line.

**WARNING!**

If you print out `hi`, then print out `hello` using `\r`, you’ll get `hillo` because the output wrote over the previous two letters. If you print out `hi` with spaces (which don’t show up here), then it will output `hi`. To fix this, print out spaces using `\r`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I coped that code, but my output is 
`Hi BobHi BobHi BobHi BobHi Bob`. 
Python 3.7.1

Comment: But Rubixred's answer worked. Weird. They look like the same method to me. The only difference I see is that `\r` is at the beginning instead of the end.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me so far

Answer (score 8):

This works on Windows and python 3.6

```
import time
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(str(x)+'\r',end='')
```

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get any of the solutions on this page to work for **IPython**, but a slight variation on @Mike-Desimone's solution did the job: instead of terminating the line with the carriage return, *start* the line with the carriage return:

```
for x in range(10):
    print '\r{0}'.format(x),
```

Additionally, this approach doesn't require the second print statement.

Comment: Even that doesn't work in PyDev console, nor does a comma after print()'s close parenthesis.

Comment: didn't work for me, it just writes the final result (ex: "Download progress 100%") once the process thing is done.

Comment: @Alexandre It works fine in IPython or its successor Jupyter. You need to flush the buffer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343688/how-to-flush-the-printed-statements-in-ipython

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not *perfect*. The line that was printed first will stay there and if your second print does not cover the entire new line, you will end up with garbage text.

To illustrate the problem save this code as a script and run it (or just take a look):

```
import time

n = 100
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        print("Progress {:2.1%}".format(j / 100), end="\r")
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print("Progress {:2.1%}".format(i / 100))
```

The output will look something like this:

```
Progress 0.0%%
Progress 1.0%%
Progress 2.0%%
Progress 3.0%%
```

What works for me is to clear the line before leaving a permanent print. Feel free to adjust to your specific problem:

```
import time

ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K' # erase line command
n = 100
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        print("Progress {:2.1%}".format(j / 100), end="\r")
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print(ERASE_LINE + "Progress {:2.1%}".format(i / 100)) # clear the line first
```

And now it prints as expected:

```
Progress 0.0%
Progress 1.0%
Progress 2.0%
Progress 3.0%
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit surprised nobody is using the backspace character. Here's one that uses it.

```
import sys
import time

secs = 1000

while True:
    time.sleep(1)  #wait for a full second to pass before assigning a second
    secs += 1  #acknowledge a second has passed

    sys.stdout.write(str(secs))

    for i in range(len(str(secs))):
        sys.stdout.write('\b')
```

Comment: make sure you flush after using this method or you might not get anything printed to screen. `sys.stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution! Windows 10, Python 3.7.1

I'm not sure why this code works, but it completely erases the original line. I compiled it from the previous answers. The other answers would just return the line to the beginning, but if you had a shorter line afterwards, it would look messed up like `hello` turns into `byelo`.

```
import sys
#include ctypes if you're on Windows
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
#end ctypes

def clearline(msg):
    CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\033[K'
    ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
    sys.stdout.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE)
    sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE+'\r')
    print(msg, end='\r')

#example
ig_usernames = ['beyonce','selenagomez']
for name in ig_usernames:
    clearline("SCRAPING COMPLETE: "+ name)
```

Output - Each line will be rewritten without any old text showing:

```
SCRAPING COMPLETE: selenagomez
```

Next line (rewritten completely on same line):

```
SCRAPING COMPLETE: beyonce
```

Answer (score 2):

(Python3) This is what worked for me. If you just use the \010 then it will leave characters, so I tweaked it a bit to make sure it's overwriting what was there. This also allows you to have something before the first print item and only removed the length of the item.

```
print("Here are some strings: ", end="")
items = ["abcd", "abcdef", "defqrs", "lmnop", "xyz"]
for item in items:
    print(item, end="")
    for i in range(len(item)): # only moving back the length of the item
        print("\010 \010", end="") # the trick!
        time.sleep(0.2) # so you can see what it's doing
```

Answer (score 2):

One more answer based on the prevous answers.

Content of pbar.py:
    import sys, shutil, datetime

```
last_line_is_progress_bar=False


def print2(print_string):
    global last_line_is_progress_bar
    if last_line_is_progress_bar:
        _delete_last_line()
        last_line_is_progress_bar=False
    print(print_string)


def _delete_last_line():
    sys.stdout.write('\b\b\r')
    sys.stdout.write(' '*shutil.get_terminal_size((80, 20)).columns)
    sys.stdout.write('\b\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()


def update_progress_bar(current, total):
    global last_line_is_progress_bar
    last_line_is_progress_bar=True

    completed_percentage = round(current / (total / 100))
    current_time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S')
    overhead_length = len(current_time+str(current))+13
    console_width = shutil.get_terminal_size((80, 20)).columns - overhead_length
    completed_width = round(console_width * completed_percentage / 100)
    not_completed_width = console_width - completed_width
    sys.stdout.write('\b\b\r')

    sys.stdout.write('{}> [{}{}] {} - {}% '.format(current_time, '#'*completed_width, '-'*not_completed_width, current,
                                        completed_percentage),)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Usage of script:

```
import time
from pbar import update_progress_bar, print2


update_progress_bar(45,200)
time.sleep(1)

update_progress_bar(70,200)
time.sleep(1)

update_progress_bar(100,200)
time.sleep(1)


update_progress_bar(130,200)
time.sleep(1)

print2('some text that will re-place current progress bar')
time.sleep(1)

update_progress_bar(111,200)
time.sleep(1)

print('\n') # without \n next line will be attached to the end of the progress bar
print('built in print function that will push progress bar one line up')
time.sleep(1)

update_progress_bar(111,200)
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to overwrite the whole line otherwise the new line will mix with the old ones if the new line is shorter.

```
import time, os
for s in ['overwrite!', 'the!', 'whole!', 'line!']:
    print(s.ljust(os.get_terminal_size().columns - 1), end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Had to use `columns - 1` on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, using Python 3.7.9 within Spyder, in Windows:

```py
from IPython.display import clear_output
from time import sleep

def print_and_overwrite(text):
    '''Remember to add print() after the last print that you want to overwrite.'''
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(text, end='\r')

for i in range(15):
    #I print the results backwards (from 15 to 1), to test shorter strings
    message = "Iteration %d out of 15" %(15-i)
    print_and_overwrite(message)
    sleep(0.5)

print() #This stops the overwriting
print("This will be on a new line")
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway if somebody wants to overprint (clear) a **many** **lines** previously printed in stdout, than this answer should be helpful for him. (Thanks Thijmen Dam for the nice article [Overwrite Previously Printed Lines](https://itnext.io/overwrite-previously-printed-lines-4218a9563527))

In ANSI console you can use special sequences:

`\033[1A` and `\033[K`

First of them lift up a cursor, second - erase a line entirely.

Example of the clearing a console (Python 3):

```
LINE_UP = '\033[1A'
LINE_CLEAR = '\033[K'
CONSOLE_HEIGHT = 24 #lines

def clear_console():
    for a in range(CONSOLE_HEIGHT):
        print(LINE_UP, end=LINE_CLEAR, flush=True)
```

or eventually simply (will clear screen and move cursor to 0,0):

```
print('\033[2J', end='', flush=True)
```

If you want just positioning cursor, then use this:

```
print('\033[<L>;<C>f', end='', flush=True)
```

where `<L>` and `<C>` are Line and Column correspondingly.

Handful reference for you [ANSI escape sequences](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based off the responses I seen in this thread I made a nice little class that should be good across all platforms.

```py
import sys
import time
    
class PrintSameLine:
    """Class to correctly print on same line.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_message = ""

    def print_msg(self, msg: str):
        print(" " * len(self.last_message), end="\r", flush=True)
        print(msg, end="\r", flush=True)
        self.last_message = msg


# Note printing in reverse so you can see how it works
prnt = PrintSameLine()

for i in reversed(range(10)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    prnt.print_msg("*" * i)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Works like a charm on macOS with Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method and it worked perfectly

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(f'\r{i}',end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```