# python - print iteration number without new line

Tags: python, printing, iteration, line

I have a loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

and it print :

```
1
2
...
8
9
```

OK

but I'm searching to make a **unique** line which actualize for each iteration like this :

```
for i in range(10):
    magic_print "this is the iteration " + i + " /10"
```

with a result like:

```
"this is the iteration <i> /10"
```

`<i>` changing dynamically

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you would like to overwrite previous prints and count up. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419488/4362607

I edited the answer according to PM 2Ring's suggestions. Thanks!

```
import sys
import time

def counter():
    for x in range(10):
        print '{0}\r'.format(x),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    print

counter()
```

Comment: Almost. You probably need `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` statement. And you could put a `time.sleep(1)` into the loop so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is the `format` function from the str object

```
for i in range(10):
    print "this is the iteration {} /10".format(i)
```