# How to hide something that you have already printed in Python

Tags: python

I am currently making a memory game where I print a few words and after a given time the words are shuffled and then one word is removed and replaced with a new one. Then I would get the user to answer which word has been removed and which word has then replaced that word. For instance, it will print:

```
CAT DOG MOUSE HORSE
```

And after 10 seconds, I would like those words to be hidden, be shuffled and replace one word with a new word so that it prints, for example:

```
DOG HORSE RABBIT CAT
```

I understand that I can use `time.sleep()` for the program to suspend the execution of any other code.

Would it be easier to essentially **"unprint"** the first set of words and then print the new one OR **replace** the first printed set of words with the new one.

Comment: You can't. Once something is printed to the console, it's there for good. If you're willing to go into simple GUI programming, then you could do it.

Comment: You could use curses (or some [variant](http://inventwithpython.com/pygcurse/) if you have Windows).

Comment: on windows you can terminate your format string with "\r" instead of "\n"                 sys.stdout.write("...\r" % (variables)
sys.stdout.flush()

Comment: @Zizouz212 that's not true. You can carriage return to the start of the line and overwrite

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a library that lets you write to screen coordinates. I've written the doscmd-screen package to do this (http://doscmd-screen.readthedocs.org/), and it would work something like:

```
import screen, time
scr = screen.Screen()
scr.writexy(scr.left, scr.top, "CAT DOG MOUSE HORSE")
time.sleep(10)
scr.writexy(scr.left, scr.top, " " * scr.width)
```

Note: the package was originally only for dos, but now also supports *nix.

Comment: Thanks :-)  Most of the heavy lifting is done by colorama, I just added functionality to fetch screen information from various system calls.. It is rather convenient in its smallness for doing simple tasks.

Comment: looks complicated :) but thank you. Its actually saying "No module named screen" am I required to download something or install something? (I have imported screen)

Comment: Yes, you need to follow the installation directions in the docs (linked to in my answer), basically `pip install doscmd-screen`.

Comment: Do you just type "pip install doscmd-screen" into my code? Because if so it says "install" is a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you're operating on the terminal, you can use `os.system('clear')` as follows:

```
import os
import time

# first statement
print('CAT DOG MOUSE HORSE')

# wait then clear
time.sleep(10)
os.system('clear')

#second statement
print('DOG HORSE RABBIT CAT')
```