# Make a blinking busy indicator on python shell

Tags: python, busyindicator

I want to make `*` flash on the command line in a 1 second interval.

```
import time
from sys import stdout

while True:
    stdout.write(' *')
    time.sleep(.5)
    stdout.write('\r  ')
    time.sleep(.5)
```

All I get is a blank line, no flashing `*`.

Why is that?

Comment: Your program works fine for me. It has to be a problem with your environment. Are you using idle?

Comment: Why not use print?

Comment: no, I am using KDE terminal "Konsole"

Comment: because print always prints a newline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out. This will print `*` on a line at intervals of 0.5 second, and show for 0.5 second (flashing as you called it)

```
import time

while True:
     print('*', flush=True, end='\r')
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print(' ', flush=True, end='\r')
     time.sleep(0.5)
```

Note that this doesn't work in IDLE, but with cmd it works fine.

Without using two print statements, you can do it this way:

```
import time

i = '*'
while True:
    print('{}\r'.format(i), end='')
    i = ' ' if i=='*' else '*'
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: prints repetitive * on Windows, end='\r' works for me

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the discussion here: [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/python-how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout)

The following code works in the IDLE environment and command line on Windows 10:

```
import time

while True:
    print('*', end="\r")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(' ', end="\r")
    time.sleep(.5)
```