# Update time display on line by overwriting not adding new lines

Tags: line, clock

I want to create a clock in python. I have this so far

```
from datetime import datetime

for i in range (99999999999):
    now = datetime.now()
    print (now)
```

This outputs the time great but it keeps generating lines whereas I want it on one line and keep updating that single line, not updating to a new line.

It does this

```
2017-04-27 20:21:47.529404
2017-04-27 20:21:47.531409
2017-04-27 20:21:47.532412
2017-04-27 20:21:47.534417
2017-04-27 20:21:47.536422
2017-04-27 20:21:47.537425
2017-04-27 20:21:47.539430
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)

Comment: Fixed grammar and improved title.