# Python: How to print on same line, clearing previous text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

In Python you can print on the same line using `\r` to move back to the start of the line.

This works well for progress bars or increasing precentage counters, eg: [Python print on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181)

However when printing lines that may decrease in length, this leaves the previous lines text there, eg:

```
import sys
for t in ['long line', '%']:
    sys.stdout.write(t + '\r')
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Leaves the terminal text as: `%ong line`.

Whats the best way to write a shorter line after a longer one, when printing to the same line?

Comment: Note that some of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524 (lower down on the page), cover this question, but the question is in fact different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout)

Comment: @karl-knechtel that question doesn't ask about the problem of trailing text being left when using `\r`.

Comment: It doesn't ask explicitly, perhaps because it didn't occur to OP as a problem; but it's a common inference, and is addressed by the top answer there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Along with `\r`, the ansi-sequence `\033[K` is needed - *erase to end of line*.

This code works as expected.

```
import sys
for t in ['long line', '%']:
    sys.stdout.write('\033[K' + t + '\r')
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

---

Note, this doesn't work when the string includes tabs, you may want to replace:

`sys.stdout.write('\033[K' + t + '\r')` with ...

`sys.stdout.write('\033[K' + t.expandtabs(2) + '\r')`

Comment: I found that the erase sequence interferes with space-expanded tabs unless you put it in a separate string like `print('\033[K' + '\tWords here'.expandtabs(2))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, added note, I'm not sure if there is a better way to solve this than what you've suggested.

Comment: Can you explain why you added the `\r` to the end of the string? I tried it with `print('\r\033[K'+t)` and it seems to work.

Comment: It can be at the beginning of the line too, the cursor will then be left at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you have been printing without a newline character at the end of your print, you can flush your latest print with:

```py
print('\r\033[K', end='')
```

If you previously printed with a new line, you can use the ANSI escape code to move up one line and to the beginning of the line with:

```py
print('\033[F', end='')
```

You can then flush the line as before.

An example usage:

```py
LINE_FLUSH = '\r\033[K'
UP_FRONT_LINE = '\033[F'
...
print(UP_FRONT_LINE + LINE_FLUSH + msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do this is to write spaces over the characters. For this, it'd be a good idea to write as many spaces are needed to cover the last line only. 
Example:

```
previousLength = 0
for t in ["long line", "%"]:
    print(" " * previousLength, end="\r") 
    print(t, end="\r")

    previousLength = len(t)

print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Technically this solution does not clear the output of previous print statement,
but is just a workaround to achieve your goal that is to write a shorter line after a longer one without excess characters of previous line.*

*A shortened version of [@M Palmer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8207126/m-palmer) answer.*

We can just print `space` characters to erase the previous output which can be done using `ljust` string method.

```
print('long line', end="\r")
print('%'.ljust(10))
```

Output:

```
%
```

More generalized way of doing this can be by saving the length of the largest string in the program and passing that lenght to `ljust`method

**However `\033[K` works best.**

Reference:

- [How can I fill out a python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676676/16187613)