# Write output in same line, clearing previous line completely on python console

Tags: python-3.x, console, command-line-interface, stdout, python-curses

This code demonstrate a progress and print `Done...` at same console line and exit the program

```
import time

filename = 'file-name.txt'

for i in range(0, 101):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print('Downloading File %s [%d%%]\r'% (filename, i), end="", flush=True)

print('Done...\r\n', end="", flush=True)
```

**problem** is when program end, it has the **remnants** of previous line at the end of the last line. bellow output demonstrate a **single line** updating while program running.

**Current Output (Single line update)**

```
Downloading File file-name.txt [1%]
.
.
Downloading File file-name.txt [100%]
Done...ding File file-name.txt [100%]
```

**Expected Output (Single line update)**

```
Downloading File file-name.txt [1%]
.
.
Downloading File file-name.txt [100%]
Done...
```

Found the same problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205/python-how-to-print-on-same-line-clearing-previous-text) but it doesn't **solve** this issue.
How can I achieve **Expected Output** without the **remnant** of previous line.
I guess adding `'\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b'` is not very pythonic

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @GoodDeeds appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This none printable character **\x1b[2K** erase current line and fixed the problem.

```
import time

filename = 'file-name.txt'

for i in range(0, 101):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print('Downloading File %s [%d%%]\r'% (filename, i), end="", flush=True)

print('\x1b[2K', end="")
print('Done...\r\n', end="", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code you provided and ran it on my system..
the output was what you expected.

````
```Downloading File file-name.txt [0%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [1%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [2%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [3%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [4%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [5%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [6%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [7%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [8%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [9%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [10%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [11%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [12%]
Downloading File file-name.txt [13%]

Downloading File file-name.txt [100%]
Done... ```
````

Comment: output show the remnant of the previous line, i edited the code after your answer to demonstrate it more clearly