# Printing with \r keeps parts of the old string

Tags: python, printing, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook on Windows. I'm trying to override previous prints, but I always get the remaining parts of previous prints:

```
print("Loooooooooooooooooooong String",end="\r",flush=True)
print("Short String",end="\r",flush=True)
```

Output: Short Stringooooooooong String

I have tried os.system('clear') and os.system('cls'), but it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: See accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205/python-how-to-print-on-same-line-clearing-previous-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to print on same line, clearing previous text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205/python-how-to-print-on-same-line-clearing-previous-text)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still get the same problem for both answers.