# How to print in same line but to eliminating characters from previous printing in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, printing, formatting, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to print in Jupyter Lab in the same line, but clearing the previous output. I'm aware of the `'\r'` escape character and that I can do `print('\r'+ my_string,end='')` and it works. The thing that I want to know is how can I completely erase the previous output, because when `my_string` has less characters, the characters from previous line output remains at the end of the line.

For example:

```
my_string = '\r{}%'
for i in range(10000,-1,-1):
    print(s.format(i/100),end='')
```

The final output for this would be 0.0%**%%**, instead of 0.0%

I tried [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205/python-how-to-print-on-same-line-clearing-previous-text), but it didn't work for me :(

EDIT: What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
my_string = '\rLap {} || {}%'
for lap in range(3):
    for i in range(10000,-1,-1):
        print(my_string.format(lap,i/100),end='')
    print()
```

Actual output:

```
Lap 0 || 0.0%%%
Lap 1 || 0.0%%%
Lap 2 || 0.0%%%
```

Desired output:

```
Lap 0 || 0.0%
Lap 1 || 0.0%
Lap 2 || 0.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IPython` to clear/overwrite the output:

```
pip install IPython
```

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output(wait=True)
```

Also try using the `os` module:

```
import os
print('Hello...')
os.system('clear') #os.system('cls') for Windows
print ("cleared!")
```

or try putting `\r` in the end argument.

```
print('', end='\r')
```

Comment: Thanks @krmogi. This would actually erase the complete output of the cell right? Isn't a way to just clear/erase the current line or how to avoid having those characters left from previous printing?

Comment: I updated my answer, try those as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried what you proposed, but I couldn't achieve it :(. I also edited the question and updated the desired output, hoping to be more clear.