# How to completely overwrite previous print with a new one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to print a progress status, so update a print with a new one. I read many post that says you have to use "\r", so I tried this: `print(string, end="\r", flush=True)`.

The problem is that when the previous printed string is bigger than the second one, some stuff of old print will reamins in the new print.

Here's the full code:

```
import time

long_string = "AAAAA"
short_string = "BB"
c = 0
while True:
    if c % 2 == 0:
        print(long_string, end="\r", flush=True)
    else:
        print(short_string, end="\r", flush=True)
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

I would expect that in the if it would print "AAAAA" and in the else it would print just "BB", but instead, in the else, it prints "BBAAA" because the "A" remains from previous print. [Here's what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE9ep.png). I would like it would be just "BB" instead of "BBAAA".

I saw this post answer [Python: How to print on same line, clearing previous text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205/python-how-to-print-on-same-line-clearing-previous-text) so I tried to use `os.sys.stdout.write('\033[K' + long_string + '\r')` instead of print, but I still have the same problem [and it also print a strange character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUhdw.png)

How can I completely delete previous clean and make a new one without traces of the old one?

**Edit:**

@Thierry Lathuille
Here's the full code with the second solution:

```
import time, os

long_string = "AAAAA"
short_string = "BB"
c = 0
while True:
    if c % 2 == 0:
        os.sys.stdout.write('\033[K' + long_string + '\r')
    else:
        os.sys.stdout.write('\033[K' + short_string + '\r')
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

It produces this output

[image: it produces this output]

I'm testing it in Windows 10 cmd.

**Edit 2:**
I said that the solution of "\r" didn't work and you closed my question and said that it has been answered in that thread. Are you kidding me right? Please open it again, that solution doesn't work, I already said it, that thread's answeres doesn't work to me and I explained why.

Comment: If the current message is shorter than the last one, add that many spaces onto the end of the short message.

Comment: You can use `short_string = "BB   "`

Comment: Please post the exact code you used with the last solution, this works perfectly in the terminal I use.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It shouldn't. You should see `BBAAA` on every other iteration instead of just `BB`

Comment: And note that this would be needed for the short string in order to erase the line before printing it, not for the long one, as in your last example.

Comment: @Barmar I put the `'\033[K' in front of each line, and it works perfectly. Maybe the OP only used it at the start of the long lines, which is useless.

Comment: If you're getting an arrow before `[`, you're using a nonstandard terminal emulator.

Comment: @mozway but in the real world case I wouldn't know how long is the string printed, so I should store its length then in the second print, put empty spaces till the previous length, and it's very unelegant solution, I'm hoping Python give us a more elegant solution

Comment: @Barmar I'm using Windows 10 cmd

Comment: @woyim46107 `\033[K` should work fine if your terminal supports it, if you print in another context (e.g. in a notebook) this might not work and the space will be a safer workaround. The issue is not python but the software that displays the output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences-in-c

Comment: @woyim46107 also, you can programmatically rework the strings: `long_string, short_string = map(''.join, zip(*itertools.zip_longest(long_string, short_string, fillvalue=' ')))`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `flush` doesn't delete the previous output, it simply **return character to place the cursor at the beginning of the line**.

`BB` has only 2 characters, so **it will override only 2 characters**, if it has 3 characters will override 3 characters and so on. For example, if `short_string = "BBB"`, the output will be `BBBAA`.

To solve this you have 2 options:

1. Make `short_string` have the same lenght of `long_string`:

   ```py
   long_string  = "AAAAA" # 5 Chars
   short_string = "BB   " # 5 Chars
   ```
2. Remove the previous output escape code:

   ```py
   import time

   long_string = "AAAAA"
   short_string = "BB"
   c = 0
   while True:
       if c % 2 == 0:
           print(long_string, end="\r")
       else:
           print(short_string, end="\r")
       c += 1
       time.sleep(1)
       print("\033[K", end="\r") # Delete previous output
   ```
3. Remove the previous output based on lenght:

   ```py
   import time

   long_string = "AAAAA"
   short_string = "BB"
   c = 0
   while True:
       if c % 2 == 0:
           print(long_string, end="\r")
       else:
           print(short_string, end="\r")
       c += 1
       time.sleep(1)
       print(" " * len(long_string), end="\r")  # Delete previous output
   ```

##### EDIT:

You [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347254/how-to-completely-overwrite-previous-print-with-a-new-one/77347360?noredirect=1#comment136358008_77347360):

> how to make work the second solution on Windows cmd too?

Well, unfortunately, this isn't possible because *Windows* doesn't support *ANSI*, it uses a different set of escape sequences.

In this case you can use this function:

```py
import os

def clear_console():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Comment: I would probably do the latter myself.

Comment: OP commented about the first solution. For the second one, how is it different from what the OP already does (see the code in his last edit)?

Comment: thank you for the reply, do you know how to make work the second solution on Windows cmd too?

Comment: I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

To completely delete previous print and make a new one without traces of the old one in one line, you can try this:

```
import time

long_string = "AAAAA"
short_string = "BB"
c = 0
while True:
    if c % 2 == 0:
        print("\r" + long_string, end="")
    else:
        print("\r" + short_string, end="")
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\r\033[K", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a compatible terminal (e.g. XTerm in Linux), the `\033[K` escape code works fine: the full line is deleted and `AAAAA` is replaced by `BB` without leaving the tailing As: `BBAAA`.

This is however not the case with other display methods (e.g. Jupyter notebook).

Padding the short string with spaces doesn't seem necessarily non-pythonic to me, especially since you can do it quite easily:

```
long_string, short_string = map(''.join,
                                zip(*zip_longest(long_string, short_string,
                                                 fillvalue=' ')))
# the above also works with a list of more than 2 strings

c = 0
while True:
    if c % 2 == 0:
        os.sys.stdout.write(long_string + '\r')
    else:
        os.sys.stdout.write(short_string + '\r')
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Or if you know which one is the sort string:

```
short_string += ' '*(len(long_string)-len(short_string))
```

Other generalization for more than 2 strings:

```
strings = ['AAAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCC', 'DD', 'E']

MAX = max(map(len, strings))

c = 0
while c<20:
    s = strings[c%len(strings)]
    os.sys.stdout.write(s + ' '*(MAX-len(s)) + '\r')
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```