# Delete a complete line in python 3 output

Tags: python, line

How can I delete a complete line in the output screen of python?

Can I use the escape sequence '\b' for this?

Comment: maybe relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking is somewhat terminal-specific. However, the following solution should work in both Linux and  Windows.

1. Write `\r` to return to the beginning of the current line.
2. Write as many spaces as needed to "cover" any previous content on the line.
3. Write `\r` to return to the beginning of the current line again.
4. Write the new text for this line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please explain step 2 in detail?

Comment: @user8718189 That part is left as an exercise to the reader. It depends on your application requirements. Either you need to write a wrapper function that keeps track of how many characters you've written, or just always write some amount like `80`.