# Cannot truncate sys.stdout; returns "io.UnsupportedOperation: truncate"

Tags: python-3.6, stdout

**FULL CODE:**

```
import sys
import time

counter = 0

while True:
    sys.stdout.write(str(counter))
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.truncate()
    counter += 1
```

**PART THAT MATTERS**

`sys.stdout.truncate()`

**QUESTION(S)**

Why does `sys.stdout.truncate()` return an error? How can I truncate `sys.stdout` if `sys.stdout.truncate()` will not work?

**OPERATING SYSTEM AND MORE INFO**

Operating System: Windows

Operating System Version: Windows 10

Programming Language: Python

Programming Language Version: Python 3.6

Other Details: Run from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.stdout is a a file object which corresponds to the interpreter’s standard output and does not have a truncate() method:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout

It seems like you want to create status bar style output. 
This should work in Python3:

```
import time

counter = 0

while True:
   print("{}".format(counter), end="\r")
   time.sleep(1)
   counter += 1
```

See [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python) for more info

Comment: Thank you, I will check if it works, because I remember hearing that \r only works for UNix-based operating systems.

Comment: It works! The thing was that I was making a text-based game, and don't want to keep on using os.system("cls"), but I need to truncate all of sys.stdout for that, but still, this is useful, for loading screens. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!