# print with line replacement in python

Tags: python-3.x

I like to print something and then replace it with the next value in a way that the previus value will disapear and the new one will replace that.
How should I do that?
e.g.
in

```
print('Hello World')

for i in range(10):
    print('Case Number {} ...'.format(i)) # I like to print with replacement here

print('Good Bye')
```

I like to have the final output like this:

```
Hello World
Case Number 9
Good Bye
```

P.S. I saw [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python) but it is not giving me answer `print('Case Number {} ...'.format(i), end='\r')` does not working for some reason.
Specifically:

```
print('Hello World')

for i in range(10):
    print('Case Number {} ...'.format(i), end='\r') # I like to print with replacement here

print('Good Bye')
```

will generate:

```
Hello World
Good Byeber 9 ...
```

Comment: You can print `"\r"` (or send it to `sys.stdout`) to return to the start of the line, but you'll need to run your code in the terminal to see this...

Comment: What do you mean by "does not working for some reason"? Does it raise an error? Does it fail to reset the cursor?

Comment: The reason you get that output is because "Good Bye" is printed on the same line... Use `print("\nGood bye")` instead...

Comment: If you want to print on a new line *after* preparing to overwrite the current line, you must print an explicit newline (``\n``) first.

Comment: I see @EdWard, \n does the magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print an extra new line after you're doing with all your in-place rewrites:

```
print('Hello World')

for i in range(10):
    print('Case Number {} ...'.format(i), end='\r') # I like to print with replacement here

print()  # Move to next line
print('Good Bye')  # Now print
```

Instead of an empty `print`, you could just prepend the string in the final `print` with a newline (`\n`), making it:

```
print('\nGood Bye')
```

but the isolated `print()` is a little clearer about intent, and doesn't require mucking with constants or string formatting or the like.