# How to fully clear a single line in a command-line application?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm trying to clear a line of the output and write a new one instead of it in a Python CLI app.
If I use the carriage return (`\r`) it doesn't clear the end of the previous line, in case if it is longer.

```
print("a longer line", end="\r")
print("a short one")
```

But I get this output (the end of the longer line is not removed):

```
a short onene
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: `print("a short one         ")` sorry there's no general and good solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105111/6451573 answers perfectly

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you for your comment. That works :) I was just wondering maybe there is another, more efficient way, than just adding spaces to the end of the string to print.