# How to empty previous output with Python print?

Tags: python, printing, flush

Following python script

```
import time

numbers = [11111, 2222, 333, 44, 5]
for number in numbers:
  print("{}".format(number), end='\r', flush=True)
  time.sleep(1)
print()
```

outputs `54321`, which is supposed to be `5`, how can I erase previous line on screen without any residues? Thanks!

Comment: You have one less number each time, so you overwrite only one less at each iteration

Comment: Hi @azro, I deliberately wrote in this way to demonstrate the problem, it seems the print statement just obeys `end` attribute not `flush`

Comment: Several of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python explain how to overwrite the previous line with blanks before writing the new characters.

Comment: the `flush` means : go and show it NOW, just that, it doesn't erase anything

Comment: Hi @Craig, still the same, as long as previous line has more characters than current line they're left there on screen

Comment: @azro do you know any method that can erase the previous line on screen... thanks!

Comment: You need to keep track of how many characters are in the previous line, as is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43952192/7517724, Or, if you know the max length of your  lines, just write that many " " characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To erase the current line use `'\x1b[2K'`
Try this:

```
import time

numbers = [11111, 2222, 333, 44, 5]
for number in numbers:
  print('\x1b[2K', end='\r')
  print("{}".format(number), end='\r')
  time.sleep(1)
```

Reference: Adapted the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105111/14066252