# Can I have my output in one line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If my code is as folllows:

```
from time import sleep
print('Hi')
sleep(1)
print('How are you?')
```

The output would be :

```
Hi
How are you?
```

How can I make it so that the output is `Hi` then after a second `Hi` changes into `How are you` in one line of the output and is not printed in another line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from time import sleep
print('Hi ', end='')
sleep(1)
print('How are you?')
```

You should get:

```
Hi How are you?
```

Comment: please do not replace existing answers on SO. It makes the site messy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python. You can flag the post as a duplicate.