# Is there a way to remove prevous prints?

Tags: python

So i am currently trying to make something that will print `.` and remove it then print `..`
and also remove it then print `...` When i tried using sys module to remove the prevous text this was the output: `lol [Ktest` so it basically adds a `[K` to the next line.
I also tried using another method so instead of removing the prevous text it would just add onto it like:

```
import time
print("lol",end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("test")
```

it did work in IDLE but when i tried to use it by opening the file in the command promt it waited for 1 second and then just gave `loltest` without any delay between them. So nothing i found in the internet worked for me.

Comment: You might be looking for the Carriage Return, `\r`, https://www.codespeedy.com/how-does-carriage-return-work-in-python/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: If this is meant to indicate progress of an operation, there are also progress bar libraries on pypi; if you find yourself writing more than a couple of lines for this, consider using one of those?

Comment: To fix the "waited 1 second then printed everything" problem, you need to use `flush=True` on the first `print`, like this: `print("lol", end="", flush=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You may print with the keyword argument `end` to append the special character `'\r'` to the end of the line.

E.g.

```
import time
print(".", end='\r')
time.sleep(2)
print("..", end='\r')
time.sleep(2)
print("...", end='\r')
time.sleep(2)
```

`'\r'` is carriage return and will return to the start of the line in some terminals, from where you can overwrite the text you just printed. Note that the behaviour might differ between terminals though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module to execute shell commands.

To clear the terminal, command required in windows is `cls` and for unix its `clear`

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

If you don't want to clear previous terminal outputs you can use flexibility of print function or the carriage return as others denoted.

```
for _ in range(3):
    print('.', end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: But it clears the whole screen, not only previous line..

Comment: And the second option does not work on the command prompt, it waits 1 second then prints "..."; we need to flush the buffer

Answer (score 1):

To print over the prvious print, you can use `end="\r`.

```sh
import time

print("lol", end="\r")
time.sleep(1)
print("test")
```

```sh
for i in range(4):
    print("."*i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ANSI escape codes, like this:

```
import sys, time

clear_line = '\x1b[1K\r'

print("lol", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()  # to force printing the text above
time.sleep(1)
print(clear_line+"test")  # Now lol replaced with test
```

Please note that ANSI codes you should use depend on the environment where the program is executing (platform, terminal, etc.).

Update: you may want to see the built-in [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module.

Comment: At some point, that path leads to the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module in the standard library...

Comment: Also this does not work on the command prompt, it waits 1 second then prints "test"; we need to flush the buffer

Comment: @JiříBaum Thank you, updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to print `.` then `..` then `...`, you don't need to remove the existing text; you can just print additional dots.

To make the dots actually appear one by one, you'll need to flush the buffers, using `flush=True`

```
import time

for _ in range(3):
  print('.', end='', flush=True)
  time.sleep(1)

print()
```

This has the advantage that it will work much more generally; almost any output method can do that, whereas ANSI codes or tricks with `\r` or clearing the screen depend on your hardware, operating system and various other things.