# How to overwrite a long string print in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I know that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python). The methods work well when the size of the string is not exceeded from a single line. Please consider the following code, which does not have a long string:

```
import time

for x in range(100):
    print(x, "times", end="\r")

    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Now consider the following code. You can see that it just clears the exceeded line not all characters of the printed string. I want the same behavior of the above code.

```
import time

for x in range(100):
    print(x, "timesjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj", end="\r")

    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Please note that I use VS code. How can I clear all characters when the size of the string is long?

Comment: What do you mean by overwrite long string? Post expected output :)

Comment: Is this not answered in your linked post? `end='\x1b[1K\r'`

Comment: I think OP's issue is that the text spans multiple lines in the terminal, which makes `\r` not work for returning to the start of the original line.  I might suggest using `curses` or similar if you need to overwrite multiple lines of text.

Comment: @Alex No, the `end='\x1b[1K\r'` does not work for me. I think it justifies the different lengths of strings. However, it does not work for my purpose.

Comment: @mohammad do you really need to clear the terminal? You can get the terminal size in advance with `shutil.get_terminal_size`. Then just print the first n characters.

Comment: `\r` doesn't clear anything; it only moves the cursor (if the terminal so interprets `\r` in that way). It's the subsequent text that *overwrites* whatever is there.

Comment: `'\x1b[1K'` *does* clear from the cursor back to the beginning of the line, *if* your terminal accepts ANSI escape codes.

Comment: It's better to use a library like `ncurses`, though, for terminal-independent manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
import time
import sys

CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'

for x in range(100):
    print(x, "timesjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj")
    sys.stdout.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE*2)
    sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE) 
    
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

And the count of `CURSOR_UP_ONE` depends on the length of the string and the width of the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the terminal size in advance:

```
from shutil import get_terminal_size


def print_width(s: str):
    tw, th = get_terminal_size((50, 20))

    if len(s) > tw:
        head, tail = s[:tw], s[tw:]
        print(head)
    else:
        print(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_really_long_str = "timesjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"

    print_width(my_really_long_str)
```

Comment: This function does the same thing. It just clears the latest exceeded line. However, I want to clear all characters of the printed string.

Comment: Just to be clear, if the string is too long you don't want to see it on the terminal?

Comment: No, I want to overwrite the printed string. Consider that the size of the string is always long and I just want to overwrite the string without going to the new line.

Comment: So you already have text on the console and if your newly printed string + what's already there exceeds the console width, you want to clear?

Comment: I edited the post. Please re-read it again if possible.