# create two "colums" in python output layout

Tags: python

I'm making a small program that pick random people in a list (a proget for school). The code works fine:

```
import numpy as np

people = ["0 = Baiesi", "1 = Balducci", "2 = Bulgarelli", "3 = Caffaggi", "4 = Caprara", "5 = Dodi", "6 = Fattore", "7 = Felici", '8 = Marcolin', '9 = Mascagni', '10 = Moretti', '11 = Moschini','12 = Patelli','13 = Sandu','14 = Spinelli','15 = Stevens','16 = Zani']

print(*people, sep = "\n")

n = int(input('Number of people to pick: '))

numbers = [i for i in list(range(len(people)))]
extracted = np.random.choice(numbers, size=n, replace=False)
 
print(extracted)
```

However I want it to have a specific layout, but I have no idea how to do it. I have done some research online but I didn't find anything that was suited for this case.

This is the current output:

[image: my output]

This is the output I am looking for:

[image: output i want]

Basically I want to create two "colums", the left one is where the list of people is, the right one is where there is the "user guided" part. I hope I explained myself well.

Has someone any idea on how it could be done?

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm gonna do it :)

Comment: Since you're on Linux, you should probably look into the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) library.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I was searching a more multi-platform solution since I'm using windows on my laptop

Comment: I don't think you can do that. There's the possibility to overwrite the current line on `stdout` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)), but I don't think you can back further. (But maybe I misunderstood your intension.)

Comment: I was thinking about using `rich` module's tables (see [here](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tables.html)),  which have a similar approach to what u are suggesting. The problem is that the table is printed "row by  row" and not "colums by colums" (if this make sense) that is what I want. Basically I want to:
1) firstly print the full list of the name
2) secondly print the "user guided" part ("Number of people to pick: ...")

Comment: But the problem is that you're asking for `input` in-between: I think there's no way back after that?