# How to alter the names I entered after they have been displayed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NAME_LEN 25

void listNames(int PEOPLE, char Lname[][NAME_LEN]);
void printNames(int PEOPLE, char Lname[][NAME_LEN]);
void getName(char name[]);

int main(void)
{
    int PEOPLE = 10;
    int member = 0;
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    char Lname[PEOPLE][NAME_LEN];
    listNames(PEOPLE, Lname);
    printNames(PEOPLE, Lname);
    return 0;
}

void listNames(int PEOPLE, char Lname[][NAME_LEN])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", Lname[i]);
        getchar();
    }
}

//Displays the names//
void printNames(int PEOPLE, char Lname[][NAME_LEN])
{
    int i;
    printf("\nList of names:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++)
    {
        printf("Names: %-15s\n", Lname[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to change the names that I already entered after they are displayed.

Comment: Call `listNames` again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Remove and replace printed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557076/c-remove-and-replace-printed-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean change based on index.

```
int idx = 0 ;
for( ; idx < PEOPLE; idx ++ ) {
  sprintf( Lname[idx], "%s", "New LName");
}
```

or change based on name itself?

```
int idx = 0 ;
for( ; idx < PEOPLE; idx ++ ) {
  if( strcmp( Lname[idx], "OriginalName") == 0 ) {
       sprintf( Lname[idx], "%s", "New LName");
       break;
  }
}
```