# Delete Characters in Python Printed Line

Tags: python

I'm writing a program where I want the cursor to print letters on the same line, but then delete them as well, as if a person was typing, made a mistake, deleted back to the mistake, and kept typing from there.

All I have so far is the ability to write them on the same line:

```
import sys, time
write = sys.stdout.write

for c in text:  
    write(c)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: You might want to look at the [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) package for unix, or an alternative for windows. The one I've used is [msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html). If you're just trying to fake out the user in a console then the '\b' character will work.

Comment: You can format code nicely by just indenting it by four spaces (or alternatively, by pasting and selecting it and then clicking the code button).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove and Replace Printed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
write('\b')  # <-- backup 1-character
```

Comment: +1, You probably want to `write('\b \b')` to have the desired effect.

Comment: I also needed to `sys.stdout.flush()`  in order to see the effect.

Answer (score 14):

Just to illustrate the great answers given by @user590028 and @Kimvais

```
sys.stdout.write('\b') # move back the cursor
sys.stdout.write(' ')  # write an empty space to override the
                       # previous written character.
sys.stdout.write('\b') # move back the cursor again.

# Combining all 3 in one shot: 
sys.stdout.write('\b \b')

# In case you want to move cursor one line up. See [1] for more reference.
sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
```

**References**
[[1] This answer by Sven Marnachin in Python Remove and Replace Printed Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/python-remove-and-replace-printed-items/5291044#5291044)
[[2] Blog post about building progress bars](http://readcodelearn.com/notes/progessbar.html)

Answer (score 7):

When you are using `print()`, you can set end as `\r`, which will replace the text in the current line with the new text.

```py
print(text, end="\r")
```