# Is there a function like print that changes based on a variable?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script where I print a variable from a list. At the moment, I am using `print("Variable: ", var, "\n")` which works but it fills up the terminal. I'd like it to only update the variable and not the text so that it stays on one line.

I tried importing `os` and adding `os.system('clear')` to the end of the loop, but I found it flashes and is unreadable. This is somewhat what I have:

```py
import jquery
import os

varList = jquery.loads(open('variables.json').read())

for varCurrent in varList:
    print ("Variable: ", varCurrent, "\n")
    # Clear the terminal
    #os.system('clear')
```

Although it works, this is completely unreadable due to the flash when the terminal clears.

Desired output: `Variable: $var` where $var updates and "Variable: " does not. Meaning no new lines and no terminal clearing.

Comment: please write the desired output in a clean way so we can assist you to achieve it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949887/delete-characters-in-python-printed-line 

write('\b')  # <-- backup 1-character

but not in all terminals its working, cause its a console reation on symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like on a typewriter, you should do a carriage return with the `'\r'` symbol:

```
import time

for x in range(10):
    print(f'\rVariable: {x}', end='')
    time.sleep(.5)
```