# Print in one line after removing previous in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print only current index in my Python code.

```py
for my_index in range(100):
    print(my_index)
```

This script currently prints like:

```
>>>python3 main.py
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

---

But I want to print only current `my_index` in one line **without** going to new line *(or adding space between)* like this:

```py
>>>python3 main.py
0
```

And then `0` cahnges to `1` like so...

```py
>>>python3 main.py
1
```

---

## I **DON'T** want it like this:

```
>>>python3 main.py
0 1 2 3 4 ...
```

*And [Python - Print in one line dynamically - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically) isn't answer to my question.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quoted questions is the EXACT duplicate. Use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173338/7505395 . You can substitute `sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % i)` by `print("\r%d%%" % i, end="")` but you need to keep the `sys.stdout.flush()` afterwards.

Comment: @alaniwi without flushing this does not work, because the writing wont be written to the console after every print, but just when convenient. with sys.stdout.flush() its the same.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Hi, sorry I already removed my comment because it largely duplicated yours. Yes you are right about the flush. But also print formatting using `%` isn't really recommended any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949887/delete-characters-in-python-printed-line) what you're looking for?

You can use `sys.stdout.write('\b \b')` to delete a character already printed to the console. *(Note: won't work in IDLE)*

A list of these "special characters" (known as *string literals*) can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: Yes! This was what I'm looking for. Thanks!