# How to delete character or line from terminal in Python?

Tags: python, terminal, python-3.8

I want to erase character or line from terminal in Python.

For example, I printed "Hello World" using `print("Hello World")`. And then I used `time.sleep(3)` to wait 3 seconds. Then I want to delete one character in terminal, so terminal will be `Hello Worl`.

So, what I want for result is:

1. When I start my program, `Hello World` prints.
2. And program sleeps 3 seconds.
3. Then text in terminal changes to `Hello Worl`.

And also, I found some solutions from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949887/delete-characters-in-python-printed-line), and `write = sys.stdout.write`, `write("\b")` but this prints `<0x08>`.

Is there any way to delete character or line in terminal?

I'm using Python 3.8 and Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: This probably depends on which terminal emulator you are using, is it just the normal windows command prompt?

Comment: I am using normal Windows terminal, **or** Pycharm terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `end='\r'` for your print statement. `\r` makes the cursor stay on the same row, so you can overwrite it.

```py
from time import sleep

print("Hello world", end='\r')
sleep(3)
print("Hello worl ")
```

Comment: This works fine, but what if I want to print several lines and erase it at once? In your code, I can overwrite only very last line.

Answer (score 2):

You should note that the `print` function ends with a newline by default. To keep the cursor at the end of the line you printed, you should use the `end` parameter inside the `print` function:

```
print("Hello World", end="", flush=True)    # Edited
```

The reason for using `end = ''` is to make the print function end with no new character rather than using the default newline.

For the next step, you can use `write = sys.stdout.write` as you mentioned from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949887/delete-characters-in-python-printed-line), and to avoid any problems in printing spare characters, you can make sure to use `write("\b \b")`.

The complete code can be written as follows:

```
import sys, time 

print("Hello World", end="")

time.sleep(3)
write = sys.stdout.write
write('\b \b')
```

---

You could also use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` function. As far as I know, one of the main differences between these two is that `print` forces you to start from a new line by default. However, with the above solution and using `end = ''` there are no concerns anymore.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but when I run your code, it just print "Hello Worl" after 3 seconds. What I want is print "Hello World" on start and after 3sec, text should be change to "Hello Worl".

Comment: @JayLee Oops! That's right! You should use `print("Hello World", end="", flush=True)` so that the buffered string gets printed on the terminal, and then you're good to go, and the code will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and you've probably found the solution, but it never hurts to help future viewers that have the same question. I see that you've commented on the answer marked correct asking if you could erase multiple lines at once. The way I would approach this is like so:

```py
import sys
import time


def go_to_start(text):
    lines = text.split('\n') # separate lines
    nlines = len(lines) # number of lines
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[%sA' % (nlines - 1)) # move up to first line
    sys.stdout.write('\r') # move to beginning of line


text = '''
this is my
multiline text
'''

text2 = '''
this is not my
multiline paragraph
'''

sys.stdout.write(text) # print text
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(3) # sleep 3 seconds
go_to_start(text) # go to start
sys.stdout.write(text2) # overwrite text
```

Now, a problem that is very rarely talked about, as far as I've noticed, arises. If `text2` were to be

```py
text2 = '''
this is
multiline
'''
```

the original text would be left unchanged. This is because when you move to the start and overwrite text, only the text that is needed to be overwritten is overwritten. In this case, only `'this is'` and `'multiline'` would be overwritten, leaving `' my'` and `' text'` untouched. To fix this, you could write a new `clear_to_start` function, that clears text as the cursor ascends to the top:

```py
def clear_to_start(text):
    lines = text.split('\n') # separate lines
    lines = lines[::-1] # reverse list
    nlines = len(lines) # number of lines

    for i, line in enumerate(lines): # iterate through lines from last to first
        sys.stdout.write('\r') # move to beginning of line
        sys.stdout.write(' ' * len(line)) # replace text with spaces (thus overwriting it)

        if i < nlines - 1: # not first line of text
            sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A') # move up one line

    sys.stdout.write('\r') # move to beginning of line again
```

This function could then be used like so:

```py
import sys
import time


def clear_to_start(text):
    lines = text.split('\n') # separate lines
    lines = lines[::-1] # reverse list
    nlines = len(lines) # number of lines

    for i, line in enumerate(lines): # iterate through lines from last to first
        sys.stdout.write('\r') # move to beginning of line
        sys.stdout.write(' ' * len(line)) # replace text with spaces (thus overwriting it)

        if i < nlines - 1: # not first line of text
            sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A') # move up one line

    sys.stdout.write('\r') # move to beginning of line again


text = '''
this is my
multiline text
'''

text2 = '''
this is
multiline
'''

sys.stdout.write(text) # print text
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(3) # sleep 3 seconds
clear_to_start(text) # clear lines and ascend to top
sys.stdout.write(text2) # overwrite text
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `\r` lets you return to the beginning of the line, while using the keyword `end` lets you avoid entering a new line.

```
from time import sleep


class ProgressBar:

    def __init__(self, length=30):
        self.length = length

    def __call__(self, value, total):
        n = int(self.length * value / (total-1))        
        full = '=' * n
        empty = ' ' * (self.length - n)
        print(end=f'\r[{full}{empty}]')


def test():
    bar = ProgressBar(length=20)
    n = 20
    for i in range(n):
        bar(value=i, total=n)
        sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

For this code to work properly you must not print while progress bar is growing.