# How can I replace a printed line with a new printed line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am looking to do is replace a print statement with a new print statement. In layman's terms, I want the console to print `Downloading...` and then replace it with `Downloading...done!` as soon as the downloading finishes. I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291044/1530429) but it just prints some garbage and then the print statement on a new line. I am using Python 3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this on the Windows console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `end=""` in the first `print`, default value of `end` is a `new line` but you can change it by passing your own value:

```
print("Downloading...",end="")
#your code here
print("Done!")
```

**output**:

```
Downloading...Done!
```

help on `print`:

```
In [3]: print?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function print>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
import time
print("Downloading... ", end='')
time.sleep(3)
print("done.")
```

you can also replace a part of the line printet before using "\r":

```
import time
print("Downloading... ", end='')
time.sleep(3)
print("\r.............. done.")
```

This of course only works as long as you don't print a newline anywhere before the carriage return character.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Print this line, and print a newline")
print ("Print this line, but not a newline", end="")
```

http://www.harshj.com/2008/12/09/the-new-print-function-in-python-3/

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a interactive `...`, i.e. it grows, you could do something like this. Just change the conditional in the `while` with something more fitting, or even use `while True` and a `if` and `break` inside the loop.

```
>>> import time
>>> def dotdotdot():
...     print("Downloading", end="")
...     a = 0
...     while a < 10:
...         print(".", end="")
...         time.sleep(1)
...         a += 1
...     print("done!")
...
>>> dotdotdot()
Downloading..........done!
```