# How can I show never ending dots ("...") in a while loop

Tags: python

Is it possible to show something like this in Python?

> Checking.
>
> Checking..
>
> Checking...
>
> Checking.

I want it to just show one line of this while the script is running, but stop when it's done. The script I want to add it to is here: https://github.com/brandonusher/Python-Scripts/blob/master/check_port.py

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/python-remove-and-replace-printed-items) might help.

Comment: in console, you can delete a character by outputing `\b`.

Comment: Kevin,  I think the duplicate linked by @Kamehameha is better -- there are several answers there and the duplicate linked there has even more answers, including one identical to the one you linked to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Output the text with no newline character, then flush stdout. Output a `\r` to make the cursor go back to the beginning of the line. Repeat until done. Don't forget to overwrite existing text.

```
while True:
  sys.stdout.write('\rfoo.  ')
  sys.stdout.flush()
  delay(100)
  sys.stdout.write('\rfoo.. ')
  sys.stdout.flush()
  delay(100)
  sys.stdout.write('\rfoo...')
  sys.stdout.flush()
  delay(100)
```

Comment: That'll work. Thanks! I can't upvote that because I don't have 15 rep, but know I would if I could