# How do I 'unprint' a line in python?

Tags: windows, python-3.x

So, for example, I could have a stopwatch that seems to have the units changing rather than repeating underneath every time they change. I have heard of many ways to do this, like \r and sys, but these do not work on my windows python 3.6.5.(this code that doesn't work is shows below:

```
def clock():
import time
for i in range(60):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i+1,end="\r seconds")
```

Comment: Please post the code that didn't work to help others to identify problem.

Comment: This question [text-progress-bar-in-the-console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console) should help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Remove and Replace Printed items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/python-remove-and-replace-printed-items)

Comment: The problem in the other question is identical, but I do not get any of the desired outcomes when using the answers referenced there on my version of python as stated in my question.

Comment: In a generic function to print reusing the current line, first clear the line, e.g. `print('\r', ' ' * (cols - 1), sep='', end='\r', flush=True)`. Then you can follow that with a generic `print(*args, **kwds)`, assuming you've set default values `kwds['end'] = ''` and `kwds['flush'] = True`. This intentionally doesn't use `end='\r'` on the output print, because a blinking cursor on the first character looks bad. You can get the column count from `cols, lines = shutil.get_terminal_size()`. Unfortunately you have to subtract a column;  the console auto-feeds at EOL (configurable in Windows 10).

Comment: So, how would I write that in code to, for example, create a clock that updates the print line rather than prints it on a new line.

Comment: Also what does any of that mean, I only know the basics of Python and when I tried to make this code work Python has no clue what any of it meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easy with ***os***

```
import os
def osClearScreen()
    os.system('cls')
def clock():
    for i in range(60):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i+1)
        osClearScreen()
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, do you know of a way to only delete a part of the screen?

Comment: print(vars... , end='\r')

Answer (score 0):

As always kids, remember to `print('...', end='\r', flush=True)` to make it happen.

Comment: This just prints it all on the same line without deleting the previous string.