# how do I delete a sentence after it is displayed in python shell?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if I could have some code which would delete a printed sentence in the python shell after a delay.
example:
`print("hello")`
`time.sleep(1)`
`then some kind of code that after the one second delay deletes print("hello")`
fyi, I use IDLE python 3.7 on windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove and Replace Printed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import time
>>> import sys
>>> def maybe_hi():
...     print('hi', end='')  # Don't print the newline yet
...     sys.stdout.flush()  # Make sure this actually prints now.
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print('\r  ')  # Return the carriage and overwrite with spaces.
...
>>> maybe_hi()
```

This usually works in terminal applications, but some of them don't handle carriage returns properly. I don't think this works in IDLE, for instance. You could also try `\b` a few times to back up the cursor one character at a time. For more advanced console shenanigans, check out curses.