# Overwriting the printed line every print for time algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, line-breaks

I am trying to write a time algorithm. However, I am having a problem successfully printing the code on the same line by overwriting the previous print

I have tried to use "\r" to print it on the same line. However, it does not work as after finishing the first minute, the seconds go like 09,19,29,39 and so on..
not sure what the problem is here.

However, if I remove the "\r", the program works fine except it prints the time in a new line every time. I want to print it in the same line.

```
import time
for i in range(24):
    for a in range(60):
        for s in range(60):
            print(i,":",a,":",s, end='\r')
            time.sleep(1)
```

I expect the output to be a just like normal time. However it isn't working the same way not sure why

Comment: I am sure this question has been asked before. Let me see...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items

Comment: It asks how to replace a print statement

Comment: yes I looked at some similiar ones from which I found out "\r". However, it still wasn't working. Turns out there was some other mistake

Comment: Oh ok then. The code worked fine for me, But maybe some problem. No problem.

Comment: The new solution as given works fine in the terminal. Was wondering why this does not work in idle?

Comment: Have you named your file after a module?? Like have you named your file time??

Comment: yeah I have, I named it time.py

Comment: The reason why that isn't working is because the time module file is name time.py. If you name it after, the new file for the time module won't be defined. It will pass an error. To delete it, type in ```import os```, then type ```os.delete("time.py")```. This will work if it is in the same directory.

Comment: i renamed the file timer code.py but still the same error

Comment: If you rename it, then it just creates a copy, not rename it. The original file is still called time.py. You have to delee it with the os module.

Comment: Is it working??

Comment: Actually, I did not rename it. I saved the file again with a new name.

Comment: Ok, that is good, but is it working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `9` character that follows `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. after the first minute is simply the `9` in the `59` that was printed in the last second of the first minute, since the single-digit seconds do not have enough width to overwrite the `9`. You can format the output of each number with a width of 2, and since we're dealing with time here, pad the numbers with leading 0:

```
import time
for i in range(24):
    for a in range(60):
        for s in range(60):
            print('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (i, a, s), end='\r')
            time.sleep(1)
```

If you run this in IDE, it will not output anything because the output is buffered until a newline character is received. You can force-flush the output with the `flush=True` argument, but then the IDE will still not output anything because the `\r` character erases the output due to the IDE's pre-processing. You can instead flush the output first before printing `\r`:

```
import time
for i in range(24):
    for a in range(60):
        for s in range(60):
            print('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (i, a, s), end='', flush=True)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('', end='\r')
```

Comment: I have just recently started using visual studio code as my editor and turns out this works fine in the terminal but just wanted to ask why doesn't it work when running in idle?

Comment: In IDE, the output is buffered and the IDE would only actually output the buffer to the screen when there is a newline character, and there is no newline character output from this code.

Comment: I tried to run the new solution and the old solution on IDLE, but it still results in the output time printed side by side

Comment: Python's IDLE does not support moving the cursor to the beginning of a line using the `\r` character at all, so it is simply not possible with IDLE. Please simply use a different IDE.