# Delete some characters of last print / Update last print [Python 3.7.3]

Tags: python-3.x

Searched a lot about this but it is not working in Python 3.7.3 Shell.

There a lot of similar question (for example [Remove and Replace Printed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items) which refers to an 8 years old Python version though), where they succesfully solve the problem using control characters `\r` and `\b`. But in my case I'm not able to solve the problem.

I would like to have an output like `amount: x/y` (where x current position and y the length of a string or a list) which is updated at each iteration, ie the part `x/y` has to be deleted and the part `x+1/y` has to be written, while keeping the string `amount:`.

What I tried so far

**(1)**

```
import sys
import time
word='simple'
for i in range(len(word)):
    if i+1 < 10:
        print('amount: '+'0'+str(i+1)+'/'+str(len(word)+1), end='\r')
    else:
        print('amount: '+str(i+1)+'/'+str(len(word)+1), end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

output

[image]

**(2)**

```
import sys
import time
word='simple'
for i in range(len(word)):
    if i+1 < 10:
        sys.stdout.write('amount: '+'0'+str(i+1)+'/'+str(len(word)))
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('amount: '+str(i+1)+'/'+str(len(word)))
    sys.stdout.write("\b \b")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

output

[image]

Comment: IDLE does not support control characters like '\r' and '\b' (see https://bugs.python.org/issue23220). Run in a shell (like Terminal on macOS and Linux).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove and Replace Printed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items)