# Overwriting printed statements in the IDLE in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a method so that when something is printed continuously, it overwrite what the previous printed statement says. for example, if I am making a counter, normally the outcome in the IDLE would be: 1 2 3 4...., but however I'm looking to rewrite/overwrite what the previous printed statement says so it say "1" for a second then "2" appears but we can no longer see "1". Any suggestions? Sorry about how wordy this question is, I was having a hard time trying to write this where another person understands.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

arr = [1,2,3,4]
for element in arr:
    print(element, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

`end='\r'` in the print statement does the trick

Comment: This fails to overwrite the entire line, for example if your `arr` is `[1234, 999, 5, 2]`

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to rewrite the entire line but the bit of code provided can be useful for another project. thank you