# Python - Hide already printed text

Tags: python

I have a problem with basic simple python. So I am making a memory game and I want to display the objects and after a delay of 5 seconds, make the text disappear.

```
import time

print("Welcome to the memory game.")
print("Choose difficulty level :")
print("1. Easy")
print("2. Medium")
print("3. Hard")
print("4. Very Hard")
x = input("press '1' for easy, '2' for medium, '3' for hard and '4' for very hard :  ")

if x == '1' :
    print("You chose level 1, easy.")
    print("I will give you 3 objects and you have to type then in the correct order to gain points.")
    print("Not cAsE SeNSitIvE")
    obj = print("Ship, Money, Python")
    time.sleep(5)
    ez = input().upper
    if ez == 'Ship, Money, Python' or ez == 'ship,money,python' or ez == 'Ship,Money,Python' or ez == 'ship, money, python' :
        print("Correct")
    else :
        print("Wrong")
        print("The answer was : Ship, Money, Python")
```

this is a part of the code. Pls help me out here   I want to hide the text
`obj = print("Ship, Money, Python")`
after a delay of 5 seconds.

Comment: can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: If you want to clear the text from the terminal, you could sleep for 5 and then use a clear command.
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
You'll have to import os and sleep

Comment: Does this answers your question ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items

Comment: let me see @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: uh no, can you please give me another solution

Comment: anyone? Help me out here pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: have simplified your check to print correctness of the input.

Try out this:

```
import time
import re

print("Welcome to the memory game.")
print("Choose difficulty level :")
print("1. Easy")
print("2. Medium")
print("3. Hard")
print("4. Very Hard")
x = input("press '1' for easy, '2' for medium, '3' for hard and '4' for very hard :  ")

if x == '1' :
    print("You chose level 1, easy.")
    print("I will give you 3 objects and you have to type then in the correct order to gain points.")
    print("Not cAsE SeNSitIvE")
    text = "Ship, Money, Python"
    obj = print(text, end="\r")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(" " * len(text))

    ez = str(input()).upper()
    if re.match(r"SHIP\s*,\s*MONEY\s*,\s*PYTHON", ez):
        print("Correct")
    else :
        print("Wrong")
        print("The answer was : Ship, Money, Python")
```

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: No, there are 2 problems 
1) Clears ALL THE code, all the text

Comment: 2) It still says 'wrong' 'the correct answer was..'

Comment: What was the input given?

Comment: lemme try the edit

Comment: Hey, man, this code worked but it has one problem, all the text on the screen gets cleared. I just want the line 'obj = ("Ship, Money, Python")' to get hidden

Comment: @TrexS. Try the newly edited code, it gives you the intended results

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot friend. The code is now functioning correctly

Comment: Cools, can you pls accept it then?

Comment: I can't upvote, i dont have reputation, im new

Comment: No problem! Thanks for accepting it! Happy Coding

Comment: Hey, can u explain what u did, so it worked. I did not understand the logic

Comment: We just hide the text using `print (" "*len(text))`, `\r` in the `print (text, end=\r)` brings the cursor back to start point of the line and hence was hidden after 5 seconds. Then using python regex we made sure that the input from the user matches the one which we expect. You can red more on python regex here: https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Ending with `"\r"` causes the next output to start at the beginning of the previous line. Then you can replace the output with an appropriate number of spaces (`" " * len(text)`).

```
# import time

print("Welcome to the memory game.")
print("Choose difficulty level :")
print("1. Easy")
print("2. Medium")
print("3. Hard")
print("4. Very Hard")
x = input("press '1' for easy, '2' for medium, '3' for hard and '4' for very hard :  ")

if x == '1' :
    print("You chose level 1, easy.")
    print("I will give you 3 objects and you have to type then in the correct order to gain points.")
    print("Not cAsE SeNSitIvE")
    text = "Ship, Money, Python"
    obj = print(text, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" " * len(text), end="\r")
    ez = input().upper()
    if ez in [string.upper() for string in 
              ['Ship, Money, Python',
               'ship,money,python',
               'Ship,Money,Python', 
               'ship, money, python']]:
        print("Correct")
    else :
        print("Wrong")
        print("The answer was : Ship, Money, Python")
```

Comment: Hey, let me check and get back to u, give me a minute

Comment: No, it's not solving the problem

Comment: The code hides perfectly, but even on typing the correct answer, it says "Wrong" "The correct answer was..."

Comment: That's a different problem. Please check what `input().upper()` looks like (you are missing brackets there, since upper is a function) and think about whether your comparison makes sense

Comment: Small update: use `end="\r"` also for the spaces to avoid newlines

Comment: @TrexS. Here is the full version, which also fixes your additional comparison issue

Comment: This works, too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. It uses `\r` to come back at the beginning of the line and `\033[K` to clear the line:

```
import time

print("Welcome to the memory game.")
print("Choose difficulty level :")
print("1. Easy")
print("2. Medium")
print("3. Hard")
print("4. Very Hard")
x = input("press '1' for easy, '2' for medium, '3' for hard and '4' for very hard :  ")

if x == '1' :
    print("You chose level 1, easy.")
    print("I will give you 3 objects and you have to type then in the correct order to gain points.")
    print("Not cAsE SeNSitIvE")
    obj = print("Ship, Money, Python", end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(5)
    print('\033[K', end='', flush=True)
    ez = input().upper
    if ez == 'Ship, Money, Python' or ez == 'ship,money,python' or ez == 'Ship,Money,Python' or ez == 'ship, money, python' :
        print("Correct")
    else :
        print("Wrong")
        print("The answer was : Ship, Money, Python")
```

Comment: It says wrong even thought I types it correctly

Answer (score 0):

How about to use buffer of showing sentences.

This is one of idea. you can modify some code lines.

```py
import os
import time

buffer = [
    "Welcome to the memory game.",
    "Choose difficulty level :",
    "1. Easy",
    "2. Medium",
    "3. Hard",
    "4. Very Hard",
    "press '1' for easy, '2' for medium, '3' for hard and '4' for very hard :  ",
]


def printing():
    os.system('clear')
    for line in buffer:
        print(line)


printing()
x = input()

if x == '1':
    buffer.append("You chose level 1, easy.")
    buffer.append("I will give you 3 objects and you have to type then in the correct order to gain points.")
    buffer.append("Not cAsE SeNSitIvE")
    printing()
    print("Ship, Money, Python")
    time.sleep(5)
    printing()
    ez = input()
    if ez == 'Ship, Money, Python' or ez == 'ship,money,python' or ez == 'Ship,Money,Python' or ez == 'ship, money, python':
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
        print("The answer was : Ship, Money, Python")
```

---

**Edit:**
if you got an warning sentence that is "TERM environment variable not set.", then you should check the value `TERM` of your terminal.

ex) `$ export TERM=xterm`

Comment: let me check, doesn't work, my friend

Comment: Does it mean that "doesn't work" is an if statement? or printing function?

Comment: You should change your if statement on your code. Because this question's point is "how to hide already printed sentence"

Comment: I do not understand what u are trying to say...See, doesn't work means that the code u gave me doesn't function properly

Comment: Uhmm... how about set environment of your terminal before running. like `export TERM=xterm`. And if you use PyCharm, then you can try to check an option (`Emulate terminal in output console`) in `Debug configurations`.