# How do I rewrite multiple console lines?

Tags: python

I want to make a game in the python console, so I need to write out lines, and then re-write them. I started building up code for it, and came up with this:

```
import sys


while 1:
  #I will calculate what to write here, and store it in display
  display = ["thing", "other thing", "2nd other thing"]

  #Move the writing start back to the beginning
  for x in display: sys.stdout.write("\r")
  #Write the contents of display
  for x in display: sys.stdout.write(x + "\n")
```

However, the code does not erase the previously written text. It just repetitively prints the display list. How can I make it erase the text?

Comment: Each OS has a logic to delete lines from the console so it is recommended to use their APIs (or specialized libraries)

Comment: Why did you add `\n` in the second print? It should be just one loop with `'\r' + x`...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Similar Answer [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)

**Method:**

You can do this by printing out as many whitespaces as you have characters on that line
However this would only be possible in a clean manner if you know the length of everything being printed.
For example if you know the length you can do the following

```py
print("\r")
print(" " * length_of_line)
print("\r")
```

Otherwise if printing long line isn't a concern, you can adopt the brute-force method of print a load of whitespaces and hope it overwrites the whole line

```py
print("\r")
print(" " * a_large_number)
print("\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `"\r"` separately from the print statement and I think you can only use it in this way with the `print` statement.

An implementation with the print statement would look like this:

```
for i in range(3): #No endless loop
    display = ["thing", "other thing", "2nd other thing"]
    for x in display: print(x, end="\r")
```

This would result in every line overwriting the previous one.
Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items), there they also discuss different methods.

Comment: If you know that this question is asked here already and is a duplicate, please don't answer it. Instead, flag it as a duplicate