# For loop in for loop not executing right

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I just wrote some code for a loading symbol that displays

```
Loading
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
```

and then repeats this five times. My only problem is after it executes that loop once, it won't repeat. Here's my code:

```
import time
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(4):
        print("Loading"+"."*y,end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove and Replace Printed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290994/remove-and-replace-printed-items)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you overwrite `Loading...` with `Loading` it will not erase the extra three dots. Try

```
print("Loading" + "." * y + "   ", end='\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is printing the line next line on existing line. To avoid this replace you code with this:-

```
import time
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(4):
        print("Loading"+"."*y,end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
    print("\n")
```

Using a line break will print the code on the next line, not on the existing line.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
for x in range(5):
    if x != 0:
        print("")
    for y in range(4):
        print("Loading" + "." * y, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
```

This will print Loading 5 times.

Comment: This code is incorrect, `IndentationError: expected an indented block` at line 2.

Comment: Hi, Rightly pointed @CiaPan. this is copy paste error :P . thanks .